# GoldenDict Alternative To Open "dict" File

Tags: android, dictionary

For a long while I have been using GoldenDict on different devices to utilize "dict.dz" and ".index" files. In other words, a skin application to load different dictionaries. Now with the upgrade to Android 13, GoldenDict keeps crashing on my devices. Could you introduce an alternative app which opens the forementioned files on Android 13?

Comment: Assuming that's StarDict DICT format, you could try [QDict](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.annie.dictionary.fork/). But without knowing the exact format, it's hard to tell which app supports it.

Comment: I have 2 files. One with the extension ".dict.dz" and another with ".index".

Comment: That doesn't tell much, as an app can name its files as it pleases. Have you tried QDict? Did it work? – Further hint: according to the [GoldenDict Wiki](http://www.goldendict.org/wiki/index.php/Supported_dictionary_formats) those files seem to be DictD format, Maybe that helps you finding a match.

Comment: Qdict does not work.